# Jquery Tablesorter plugin with mixed decimal point numbers

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

Been looking around for how to sort mixed numbers using the Jquery tablesorter plugin (http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/#Introduction)

When I sort by totals it is displayed as the following:

170.5 

 65.5 

 63.5 

 505 

 263 

 218 

 187

So basically atm the plugin is just ignoring the "." and makes the top number 1705. Sorry if I have just missed the answer somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check for whitespace around your numbers that might be tricking tablesorter into thinking they are strings. See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/mzuN7/2/) - when run like this, it sorts correctly:

```
<table id="tablesorter" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Mixed Numbers</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>170.5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>65.5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>63.5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>505</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>263</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>218</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>187</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

$(function () {
    $("#tablesorter").tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        widgets: ['zebra']
    });
});
```